# stream azure blob video to JWPlayer

Tags: asp.net, azure, video-streaming, blob, jwplayer

i need a working code by which I can stream videos from my azure blob storage to jwplayer, I tried it on myself and getting error can not run play list due to cross-domain policy restrictions.
I uploaded my video to azure and accessing via http://.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/03/cross-domain-handling-on-azure-blob.html

It is talking about Silverlight but the process should be the same.  For the crossdomain.xml file, take a look at how it was setup here:

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?14553-crossdomain-policy-issue-with-jwplayer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you do not have a "clientaccesspolicy.xml" file at the $root level of your azure storage account containers.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<access-policy> -<cross-domain-access> -<policy> -<allow-from http-request-headers="*" http-methods="*"> <domain uri="*"/> <domain uri="http://*"/> </allow-from> -<grant-to> <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/> </grant-to> </policy> </cross-domain-access> </access-policy>
```

Comment: Oh - my bad - was thinking about silverlight, as Tom said you'll need a crossdomain.xml.  Same idea, same location.  Details here:  http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12541/crossdomain-file-loading-restrictions